# .NET in Windows ME

Tags: c++, c#, windows, .net

So I'm used to work with C# and I recently started studying C++. So I have a Vista computer, which I'm using right now, but I also have an old Windows Millennium Edition Computer, and I also wanna work with it. It has a Visual Studio, but when I try to open it, it says that the computer can't start the program. There's no C# nor C++ nor anything installed, I tried but it wasn't compatible. So what I'm asking for is:

**.NET Software Development Kit**

**It has to be compatible with Windows ME. It also needs to be installed with an offline setup (My ME computer only supported Internet by cable phone or something, and I don't have it)**

Is it possible?! If so, how to get it?

**Thanks for the time**

Comment: This doesn't look like much of a question. You should reword your post to reflect an actual question, rather than simply stating your problem. The purpose of this site is to answer and archive questions, rather than simply fix someones problem.

Comment: This is not even game development related.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't ask this in StackOverflow... :(

Comment: Why do people hate this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some ways, your question is analogous to trying to run a Super Nintendo game on the original NES.  If you have limited OS features, you should probably not try to develop using a high-overhead, modern framework (designed for modern OS features.)  I wonder why you want to use .NET at all.

Regardless, your question made for a fun little research project, so here's what I found.

- For XNA, the answer is no.  Windows 7, Windows XP
  (See System Requirements) http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27599
- For the newest directX, also no.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27599
- If you only want to run the .NET framework on windows ME, you may install a version up to 2.0! (No service packs.)

  > Version 2.0 without any Service Pack is the last version with support for Windows 98 and Windows Me.
  >   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_2.0

For the old computer, you might want to abandon the .NET idea.  You can wipe it, install linux, and learn to write C++ by doing everything the hard way.  Make games that are fun without using managed code.  Then when you've mastered the language features, you can buy modern hardware and marvel at how much it simplifies everything.

Comment: Can I program Windows Forms Applications without the .NET framework?